# Opengl ES 2.0 Camera jerks player when moving

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to create simple game on Android using OpenGL.

I'm running game on 2 threads. One for rendering one for moving objects around. The problem is, when I try and follow player with camera, player starts to jerk. (See the youtube link, for screen recording)

I have try to move camera in 2 different ways. Firstly I tried to move it on top of player (camera x,y is the same as player x,y). Secondly I tried to move it as elastic/spring to follow player. Jerking occurs in both scenarios.

http://youtu.be/5DXuYuaabvM  (camera on top of player)

http://youtu.be/4M-udbu2Vfc  (camera elastic spring)

I have tried to print player and camera x position while moving, and it doesn't look like they move uniformly. What is even stranger is that the green fish doesn't jerk, but moves at approximately same speed as player.

Here is quick sketch up of thread design.

[image: Thread design]

(Player is movement speed / direction is controller by accelerometer.)

EDIT (After mikkokoo's answer):
After researching problem some more, I found out this "phenomenom" is called camera stutter.
The problem is as Mikkokoo's stated that sprite moves while renderer is still drawing him, some drops in fps (even small ones) also contribute toward this event.

A simple solution is to do all the work on the renderer thread.
A better solution would be to somehow synchronize renderer and "work" thread. Firstly it is good to fix your fps (both renderer's and work thread). We left renderers as it is, since it's fixed by vsync, worker thread on the other hand we fixed to 120fps.
Because in our case only player (jelly) was stuttering we changed his step to be done on renderer thread. This basically fixed stuttering, the additional workload on renderer's thread is minimum, since only 3 additional matrix operations (rotate, translate, scale) need to be done.

If you are starting from the beginning with your engine, I would probably look how implementing  2 "holder" modelViewMatrix for each sprite. Then when you are moving sprite you always move it on holderMatrix, and draw it from the other one. After drawing is completed, you can just change holder and "real" matrix. This will basically eliminate problem of changing matrix while it's drawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks like the jellyfish moves between your `getPlayerlocation` and the `drawSprite` for jellyfish.

Try using the same coordinates for the camera matrix and for drawing the jellyfish (the ones you get from `getPlayerlocation`).